# how can I make a webpage reload when the content of another webpage changes

Tags: javascript, html, forms, file-upload

I am current working on an application that allows a user to upload a file via a html form, to a server which would then process the file using several different methods. I was wondering if there would be a way to poll the server every so often to check the status of the file processing in order to determine when it would be appropriate to refresh the webpage. Or maybe some sort of webpage with a push interface. I was thinking javascript might work for this type of thing, but I am not entirely sure as to how I should go about doing this. Having said this, I was wondering If anyone could offer any advice for this? thanks! (the file processing is done via bash as well as a few other scripts on the server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most pragmatic thing to do would be to setInterval with an ajax call to check the status on the server, then clearInterval when it's done. If you are running Node.js then use Socket.io / Now.js to push status updates via html5 websockets. It just depends on what the browser support requirements are.

Comment: with the ajax call, would you know of any tutorials/examples of such a setup?

Comment: if you're using php then just create a script that checks the database (or whatever) and tells you yes or no if it's done or not. Then on the client side, just do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/mLPXt/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the 'X-Progress-ID' parameter to the HTTP post request header so that you can check the file upload progress. You can check the status throw periodic ajax calls. Don't forget to handle this operation at the server.
Another approach would be to enable the push notification throw HTML5 websockets. Then, there would be an event  that would trigger some javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

[ajaxform](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload) solves this problem for you. It accepts an uploadProgress callback. All it does is listen to the [XHR progress event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress).